# TypeScript: Tell object which keys and values it can have

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a type that represents one of certain constants. Each type also has a specific callback function.

```
type MyType = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

// Same for 'B', 'C' etc.
type callbackForA = (result: ResultForA) => void;
```

`ResultForA` is a specific object for that belongs to `A`.

I want to create a TypeScript `type` or `interface` (let's call it `MagicType`) for an object which *may have* a key for each of these `MyType` constants. The value for each of these keys can either be `true` (or implicitly `undefined` hence *"may have"*) or a maybe a callback function with a specific call signature based on the type.

The following should be a valid `MagicType` object:

```
const myObject: MagicType = {
  'A': true | (result: ResultForA) => void,
  'C': true;
}
```

where `B` is not configured, and `C` doesn't take a callback.

The following should be an invalid object for `MagicType`.

```
const myObject: MagicType = {
  'A': true | (result: ResultForB) => void;
  'FOO': true
}
```

because `A` has the wrong callback function `(result: ResultForB) => void` and `FOO` is not a valid option for `MyType`.

How can you implement such a type?

---

What I tried, is extending the `Result` type like this:

```
type CallbackFunctionVariadicAnyReturn = (...args: any[]) => any

interface MagicType extends Record<MyType, true | CallbackFunctionVariadicAnyReturn>;
```

Unfortunately, it neither detects superflous keys such as `FOO` nor does it detect wrong callback functions.

---

Bonus thought / question:

Is there also a way to tightly couple the callbacks to each `MyType` value? Maybe a tuple like this?

```
type MyTypePairs = ['A', (result: ResultForA) => void] | ['B', // ...
```

Comment: Please let me know if this https://tsplay.dev/w6XX0m meets your requirements

Comment: *"ResultForA is a specific object for that belongs to A."* - assuming by A you mean the string literal `'A'`, what does it mean for an object to belong to a string literal? Also, is `ResultForA` really an object, or is it a type? Then, when you are declaring `const myObject`, you wrote `true | (result: ResultForA) => void` which looks like a type, but you are using it as if it is a value. Your question in its current form is missing details, it is not good to make people guess what you mean; please edit to make a [mcve].

Comment: @captain-yossarian this is perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to create map data structure, which will map each allowed key to some type/value.
Consider this example:

```js
type MyMap = {
  A: "#A",
  B: '#B',
  C: '#C'
}

type MyType = keyof MyMap


type ResultForA = '#A'
type ResultForB = '#B'
type ResultForC = '#C'

type MagicType<Dict> = {
  [Prop in keyof Dict]?: true | ((value: Dict[Prop]) => void)
}

type Result = MagicType<MyMap>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAWQgghlOBeOBvUc4CCAXHAEQDEBpANHnAEIkDk59TtI+Aws+V06AC+oUJFiIIAFWjwsAaxgQA9gDMJqKCJCiZcAEowAzgFcANmABiSgE4FMcFgQHhdBk+avX69lmx3i3M0sbLh8+Z394VABzAEsAY2lYAB4AEQSwAD57XE44AG0ABWsldFiAOzgFZTV0+LAAXQB+EjBrY3gAHzgACh6ANxRTDpI6sCKSqAaASkxs-qVYgBNpoS0xeEDzexiEpJhkpA1MrSA)

Type `MyMap` is a map data structure, as you might have guess.

`MagicType` is built with help of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type MagicType = {
    'A': boolean | (result: ResultForA) => void,
    'B': undefined,
    'C': boolean,
}
```

What that does is adds type annotations for each of the three keys, and because TS won't allow any keys other than those that are listed, you can't do the `'FOO'` key, and the annotation on the callback means you can't do the `(result: ResultForB) => void` callback on a.

Answer (score 0):

see [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFMDMEsDtKgJ4HsCuAnUAXZAHSAZwFgAoPQ0AJWPQBscAxVTAQVAF5QBvUAQwBcoIjkwIA5qAC+AbnLkEOSJmj8AxklpEGOAMKp69SOpyxU8XuVCg2w7bpbtZNkKHX9L6Iknj8AtpDguARI-PSw-KRkNgBCwnwARsKJqIaQnjIubqwisP749MigCBGIKBjYmHSMIYTRNnoJ7sLw6P6JKlnk0gpkbrEW3rgAFhgSIzigYACO6MRmFoLklFo1zOjw6gA8ANKgkAAeyvDgRKAA1pBo0DTrBkYmi-AAfFygABTVOoz294bGUzmeAAbV2AF0AJRcN4AN1QsHA8jI5DcABVIEZQKhEgArJ6gADuI1g6hGl2u508wVh4Xm51gUw8lhG-FhkBWoVAAFl+BJSWiudwAAr8TBmcLbHhgkqWK43O4-fQAp7A8F-JVMTY7XZvAA+oFS6U80heyL6biOAUKxD66gsolAEjS4AAjMJefz1IKqNw+DkLtZbMIxPMADRB+KfTDNZKGtLGTLSaGcN48IM2e3wIjpAB09FQEi+kORNmkEbIcjtDqmztQ4AATB6+QKhbxpmBUIGYsHo80hCIxJIZCm0+XI8IvrGUgmMpZkzCrD3Mw68wWi5gS0Hxz2mqA1PQfD1zWQs47Evw3c2vT6kH6gyxUCHMOGOwdMJhWD1q9mphfG9era+u2E59u26itO0nTYAuqbtpaH5fsu7irsY+aFh8ADk8CoFM-BOi6hqYVuPY7lWZBAA)

```js
// define your types
type ResultForA = { a: string };

interface ResultCollection {
  A: ResultForA;  // can use named type alias
  B: { b: boolean }; // or simply inline your result types
  C: { c: number };
}

// Bonus thought / question:
type ResultFunc<K extends keyof ResultCollection> = (result: ResultCollection[K]) => void;

// Tell object which keys and values it can have
type MagicType = Partial<{[K in keyof ResultCollection]: ResultFunc<K> | boolean}>;


// examples

const good1: MagicType = { // ok
  A: true,
  B: (r: { b: boolean }) => {
    console.log(r);
  },
};

const good2: MagicType = { // ok
  A: (r: { a: string }) => {},
  B: (r: { b: boolean }) => {
    console.log(r);
  },
  C: false
};

const bad1: MagicType = {
  Foo: true, // error
}

const bad2: MagicType = { 
  B: (r: { c: number }) => { // error
    console.log('not a good b');
  },
};
```